# Java While loop won't loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, calculator

```
package pack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cont = "Yes";

        while(cont == "Yes" || cont == "yes" ){
            System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
            int x = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter another Number: ");
            int y = scan.nextInt();

            int diff = x - y;
            int sum = x + y;
            int prod = x * y;
            int quot = x / y;

            System.out.println("The Sum is: " + sum);
            System.out.println("The Diffrence is: " + diff);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + prod);
            System.out.println("The quotient is: " + quot);

            System.out.print("Enter Yes to Continue: ");
            cont = scan.next();
            System.out.println(cont);

        }

    }



}
```

This entire code works, but the while loop doesn't repeat. The `cont = scan.next();` is catching the string. The output looks like this:

```
[

Enter a Number: 5

Enter another Number: 6

The Sum is: 11

The Diffrence is: -1

The Product is: 30

The quotient is: 0

Enter Yes to Continue: Yes

Yes

]
```

Then the program terminates without any problems. All I need it to get the while loop to repeat. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to use `equals()` when you are comparing `Strings`.

Answer (score 8):

Compare Strings with `.equals` instead of `==`

```
while(cont.equals("Yes") || cont.equals("yes") )
```

Or even better:

```
while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```

Comment: added tip: use .equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: @ljgw good idea, I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to need to compare the `Strings` this way:

```
while("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(cont))...
```

That's because when using input, you won't have `String` *literals*, but `String` *objects*. Those need to be compared via `equals()` and not `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while(cont == "Yes" || cont == "yes" ){
```

As

```
while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```

Reason

You need to know the reason behind `==` and `equals()`

`equals()` method is present in the `java.lang.Object` class and it is expected to check for the equivalence of the state of objects!. That means, the contents of the objects. Whereas the `==` operator is expected to check the actual object instances are same or not.

*Example  with `if` statement*

Consider two different reference variables `str1` and `str2`

```
str1 = new String("abc");
str2 = new String("abc");
```

if you use the `equals()`

```
System.out.println((str1.equals(str2))?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

You will get the output as `TRUE`

if you use `==`

```
 System.out.println((str1==str2)?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

Now you will get the `FALSE` as output because both `str1` and `str2` are pointing to two different objects even though both of them share the same string content. It is because of `new String()` everytime a new object is created.

Answer (score 0):

instead of (cont == "Yes" || cont == "yes" ) you should use (cont.equals("Yes") || cont.equals("Yes"))

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
 while(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```